# Integrated web camera stops working when I slightly move the laptop

Tags: 14.04, video, skype, webcam, cheese

When I am working with applications that use web camera (cheese, skype) It works fine. But if I slightly move the screen of my laptop It stops showing. After application restart web cam is working again.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 and Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E130.

Here is the output of `dmesg` after I slightly moved the laptop using cheese.

```
[ 3155.738215] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 15
[ 3155.776773] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 3155.776802] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 3385 at /build/linux-gorft9/linux-3.13.0/fs/sysfs/group.c:214 sysfs_remove_group+0xc6/0xd0()
[ 3155.776808] sysfs group ffffffff81cac4e0 not found for kobject 'event12'
[ 3155.776812] Modules linked in: cuse rfcomm bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core bluetooth videodev wl(POX) intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul i915 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek cryptd snd_hda_intel drm_kms_helper cfg80211 snd_hda_codec drm joydev serio_raw snd_hwdep snd_pcm thinkpad_acpi rtsx_pci_ms lpc_ich memstick mei_me i2c_algo_bit snd_page_alloc wmi shpchp nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq mei snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore video mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc r8169 mii psmouse ahci libahci rtsx_pci
[ 3155.776918] CPU: 1 PID: 3385 Comm: cheese Tainted: P        W  OX 3.13.0-87-generic #133-Ubuntu
[ 3155.776922] Hardware name: LENOVO 33585GG/33585GG, BIOS H4ET67WW (2.06 ) 10/18/2012
[ 3155.776926]  0000000000000000 ffff880035479c18 ffffffff81729866 ffff880035479c60
[ 3155.776934]  0000000000000009 ffff880035479c50 ffffffff8106982d 0000000000000000
[ 3155.776941]  ffffffff81cac4e0 ffff8800552d20c0 ffff88006c645248 ffff8801182ab060
[ 3155.776948] Call Trace:
[ 3155.776960]  [<ffffffff81729866>] dump_stack+0x64/0x82
[ 3155.776969]  [<ffffffff8106982d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[ 3155.776975]  [<ffffffff8106989c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
[ 3155.776983]  [<ffffffff81239a3e>] ? sysfs_get_dirent_ns+0x4e/0x70
[ 3155.776990]  [<ffffffff8123ace6>] sysfs_remove_group+0xc6/0xd0
[ 3155.776999]  [<ffffffff814a47a3>] dpm_sysfs_remove+0x43/0x50
[ 3155.777005]  [<ffffffff8149a1d5>] device_del+0x45/0x1c0
[ 3155.777015]  [<ffffffff81596ca3>] evdev_disconnect+0x23/0x60
[ 3155.777023]  [<ffffffff815933f5>] __input_unregister_device+0xc5/0x1b0
[ 3155.777031]  [<ffffffff8159358d>] input_unregister_device+0x4d/0x80
[ 3155.777043]  [<ffffffffa0a44d32>] uvc_status_cleanup+0x42/0x50 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.777052]  [<ffffffffa0a3a1e8>] uvc_delete+0x18/0x140 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.777060]  [<ffffffffa0a3a40d>] uvc_release+0x2d/0x30 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.777075]  [<ffffffffa0a70789>] v4l2_device_release+0xb9/0xe0 [videodev]
[ 3155.777082]  [<ffffffff81499802>] device_release+0x32/0xa0
[ 3155.777092]  [<ffffffff8136c4b7>] kobject_cleanup+0x77/0x1b0
[ 3155.777099]  [<ffffffff8136c358>] kobject_put+0x28/0x60
[ 3155.777105]  [<ffffffff81499af7>] put_device+0x17/0x20
[ 3155.777117]  [<ffffffffa0a6f44a>] v4l2_release+0x4a/0x80 [videodev]
[ 3155.777127]  [<ffffffff811c2c64>] __fput+0xe4/0x260
[ 3155.777135]  [<ffffffff811c2e2e>] ____fput+0xe/0x10
[ 3155.777142]  [<ffffffff8108a9dc>] task_work_run+0xac/0xd0
[ 3155.777151]  [<ffffffff81014e77>] do_notify_resume+0x97/0xb0
[ 3155.777160]  [<ffffffff8173a69a>] int_signal+0x12/0x17
[ 3155.777165] ---[ end trace 3f9c80825ed62b4c ]---
[ 3155.788752] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 3155.788775] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 3385 at /build/linux-gorft9/linux-3.13.0/fs/sysfs/group.c:214 sysfs_remove_group+0xc6/0xd0()
[ 3155.788779] sysfs group ffffffff81cac4e0 not found for kobject 'input23'
[ 3155.788782] Modules linked in: cuse rfcomm bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core bluetooth videodev wl(POX) intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul i915 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek cryptd snd_hda_intel drm_kms_helper cfg80211 snd_hda_codec drm joydev serio_raw snd_hwdep snd_pcm thinkpad_acpi rtsx_pci_ms lpc_ich memstick mei_me i2c_algo_bit snd_page_alloc wmi shpchp nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq mei snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore video mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc r8169 mii psmouse ahci libahci rtsx_pci
[ 3155.788893] CPU: 1 PID: 3385 Comm: cheese Tainted: P        W  OX 3.13.0-87-generic #133-Ubuntu
[ 3155.788897] Hardware name: LENOVO 33585GG/33585GG, BIOS H4ET67WW (2.06 ) 10/18/2012
[ 3155.788901]  0000000000000000 ffff880035479c40 ffffffff81729866 ffff880035479c88
[ 3155.788909]  0000000000000009 ffff880035479c78 ffffffff8106982d 0000000000000000
[ 3155.788916]  ffffffff81cac4e0 ffff88006c645258 ffff880055143430 ffff8801182ab060
[ 3155.788923] Call Trace:
[ 3155.788936]  [<ffffffff81729866>] dump_stack+0x64/0x82
[ 3155.788946]  [<ffffffff8106982d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[ 3155.788952]  [<ffffffff8106989c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
[ 3155.788960]  [<ffffffff81239a3e>] ? sysfs_get_dirent_ns+0x4e/0x70
[ 3155.788967]  [<ffffffff8123ace6>] sysfs_remove_group+0xc6/0xd0
[ 3155.788976]  [<ffffffff814a47a3>] dpm_sysfs_remove+0x43/0x50
[ 3155.788983]  [<ffffffff8149a1d5>] device_del+0x45/0x1c0
[ 3155.788993]  [<ffffffff81593483>] __input_unregister_device+0x153/0x1b0
[ 3155.789000]  [<ffffffff8159358d>] input_unregister_device+0x4d/0x80
[ 3155.789013]  [<ffffffffa0a44d32>] uvc_status_cleanup+0x42/0x50 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.789021]  [<ffffffffa0a3a1e8>] uvc_delete+0x18/0x140 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.789030]  [<ffffffffa0a3a40d>] uvc_release+0x2d/0x30 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.789045]  [<ffffffffa0a70789>] v4l2_device_release+0xb9/0xe0 [videodev]
[ 3155.789052]  [<ffffffff81499802>] device_release+0x32/0xa0
[ 3155.789062]  [<ffffffff8136c4b7>] kobject_cleanup+0x77/0x1b0
[ 3155.789070]  [<ffffffff8136c358>] kobject_put+0x28/0x60
[ 3155.789075]  [<ffffffff81499af7>] put_device+0x17/0x20
[ 3155.789088]  [<ffffffffa0a6f44a>] v4l2_release+0x4a/0x80 [videodev]
[ 3155.789097]  [<ffffffff811c2c64>] __fput+0xe4/0x260
[ 3155.789106]  [<ffffffff811c2e2e>] ____fput+0xe/0x10
[ 3155.789112]  [<ffffffff8108a9dc>] task_work_run+0xac/0xd0
[ 3155.789122]  [<ffffffff81014e77>] do_notify_resume+0x97/0xb0
[ 3155.789131]  [<ffffffff8173a69a>] int_signal+0x12/0x17
[ 3155.789136] ---[ end trace 3f9c80825ed62b4d ]---
[ 3155.789154] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 3155.789162] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 3385 at /build/linux-gorft9/linux-3.13.0/fs/sysfs/group.c:214 sysfs_remove_group+0xc6/0xd0()
[ 3155.789166] sysfs group ffffffff81cd0d00 not found for kobject 'input23'
[ 3155.789168] Modules linked in: cuse rfcomm bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core bluetooth videodev wl(POX) intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul i915 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek cryptd snd_hda_intel drm_kms_helper cfg80211 snd_hda_codec drm joydev serio_raw snd_hwdep snd_pcm thinkpad_acpi rtsx_pci_ms lpc_ich memstick mei_me i2c_algo_bit snd_page_alloc wmi shpchp nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq mei snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore video mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc r8169 mii psmouse ahci libahci rtsx_pci
[ 3155.789252] CPU: 1 PID: 3385 Comm: cheese Tainted: P        W  OX 3.13.0-87-generic #133-Ubuntu
[ 3155.789255] Hardware name: LENOVO 33585GG/33585GG, BIOS H4ET67WW (2.06 ) 10/18/2012
[ 3155.789258]  0000000000000000 ffff880035479c00 ffffffff81729866 ffff880035479c48
[ 3155.789265]  0000000000000009 ffff880035479c38 ffffffff8106982d 0000000000000000
[ 3155.789271]  ffffffff81cd0d00 ffff88006c645258 ffffffff81cd0b00 ffff8801182ab060
[ 3155.789278] Call Trace:
[ 3155.789285]  [<ffffffff81729866>] dump_stack+0x64/0x82
[ 3155.789291]  [<ffffffff8106982d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[ 3155.789298]  [<ffffffff8106989c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
[ 3155.789305]  [<ffffffff81239a3e>] ? sysfs_get_dirent_ns+0x4e/0x70
[ 3155.789311]  [<ffffffff8123ace6>] sysfs_remove_group+0xc6/0xd0
[ 3155.789318]  [<ffffffff8123adc3>] sysfs_remove_groups+0x33/0x50
[ 3155.789328]  [<ffffffff8149973e>] device_remove_attrs+0x5e/0x80
[ 3155.789334]  [<ffffffff8149a2b1>] device_del+0x121/0x1c0
[ 3155.789343]  [<ffffffff81593483>] __input_unregister_device+0x153/0x1b0
[ 3155.789350]  [<ffffffff8159358d>] input_unregister_device+0x4d/0x80
[ 3155.789360]  [<ffffffffa0a44d32>] uvc_status_cleanup+0x42/0x50 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.789368]  [<ffffffffa0a3a1e8>] uvc_delete+0x18/0x140 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.789376]  [<ffffffffa0a3a40d>] uvc_release+0x2d/0x30 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.789389]  [<ffffffffa0a70789>] v4l2_device_release+0xb9/0xe0 [videodev]
[ 3155.789395]  [<ffffffff81499802>] device_release+0x32/0xa0
[ 3155.789403]  [<ffffffff8136c4b7>] kobject_cleanup+0x77/0x1b0
[ 3155.789410]  [<ffffffff8136c358>] kobject_put+0x28/0x60
[ 3155.789416]  [<ffffffff81499af7>] put_device+0x17/0x20
[ 3155.789428]  [<ffffffffa0a6f44a>] v4l2_release+0x4a/0x80 [videodev]
[ 3155.789436]  [<ffffffff811c2c64>] __fput+0xe4/0x260
[ 3155.789445]  [<ffffffff811c2e2e>] ____fput+0xe/0x10
[ 3155.789450]  [<ffffffff8108a9dc>] task_work_run+0xac/0xd0
[ 3155.789458]  [<ffffffff81014e77>] do_notify_resume+0x97/0xb0
[ 3155.789465]  [<ffffffff8173a69a>] int_signal+0x12/0x17
[ 3155.789469] ---[ end trace 3f9c80825ed62b4e ]---
[ 3155.789473] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 3155.789479] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 3385 at /build/linux-gorft9/linux-3.13.0/fs/sysfs/group.c:214 sysfs_remove_group+0xc6/0xd0()
[ 3155.789483] sysfs group ffffffff81cd0b60 not found for kobject 'input23'
[ 3155.789485] Modules linked in: cuse rfcomm bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core bluetooth videodev wl(POX) intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul i915 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek cryptd snd_hda_intel drm_kms_helper cfg80211 snd_hda_codec drm joydev serio_raw snd_hwdep snd_pcm thinkpad_acpi rtsx_pci_ms lpc_ich memstick mei_me i2c_algo_bit snd_page_alloc wmi shpchp nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq mei snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore video mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc r8169 mii psmouse ahci libahci rtsx_pci
[ 3155.789568] CPU: 1 PID: 3385 Comm: cheese Tainted: P        W  OX 3.13.0-87-generic #133-Ubuntu
[ 3155.789571] Hardware name: LENOVO 33585GG/33585GG, BIOS H4ET67WW (2.06 ) 10/18/2012
[ 3155.789574]  0000000000000000 ffff880035479c00 ffffffff81729866 ffff880035479c48
[ 3155.789580]  0000000000000009 ffff880035479c38 ffffffff8106982d 0000000000000000
[ 3155.789586]  ffffffff81cd0b60 ffff88006c645258 ffffffff81cd0b00 ffff8801182ab060
[ 3155.789593] Call Trace:
[ 3155.789599]  [<ffffffff81729866>] dump_stack+0x64/0x82
[ 3155.789606]  [<ffffffff8106982d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[ 3155.789612]  [<ffffffff8106989c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
[ 3155.789619]  [<ffffffff81239a3e>] ? sysfs_get_dirent_ns+0x4e/0x70
[ 3155.789625]  [<ffffffff8123ace6>] sysfs_remove_group+0xc6/0xd0
[ 3155.789632]  [<ffffffff8123adc3>] sysfs_remove_groups+0x33/0x50
[ 3155.789640]  [<ffffffff8149973e>] device_remove_attrs+0x5e/0x80
[ 3155.789646]  [<ffffffff8149a2b1>] device_del+0x121/0x1c0
[ 3155.789654]  [<ffffffff81593483>] __input_unregister_device+0x153/0x1b0
[ 3155.789661]  [<ffffffff8159358d>] input_unregister_device+0x4d/0x80
[ 3155.789671]  [<ffffffffa0a44d32>] uvc_status_cleanup+0x42/0x50 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.789679]  [<ffffffffa0a3a1e8>] uvc_delete+0x18/0x140 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.789687]  [<ffffffffa0a3a40d>] uvc_release+0x2d/0x30 [uvcvideo]
[ 3155.789700]  [<ffffffffa0a70789>] v4l2_device_release+0xb9/0xe0 [videodev]
[ 3155.789705]  [<ffffffff81499802>] device_release+0x32/0xa0
[ 3155.789713]  [<ffffffff8136c4b7>] kobject_cleanup+0x77/0x1b0
[ 3155.789720]  [<ffffffff8136c358>] kobject_put+0x28/0x60
[ 3155.789725]  [<ffffffff81499af7>] put_device+0x17/0x20
[ 3155.789738]  [<ffffffffa0a6f44a>] v4l2_release+0x4a/0x80 [videodev]
[ 3155.789746]  [<ffffffff811c2c64>] __fput+0xe4/0x260
[ 3155.789754]  [<ffffffff811c2e2e>] ____fput+0xe/0x10
[ 3155.789759]  [<ffffffff8108a9dc>] task_work_run+0xac/0xd0
[ 3155.789767]  [<ffffffff81014e77>] do_notify_resume+0x97/0xb0
[ 3155.789774]  [<ffffffff8173a69a>] int_signal+0x12/0x17
[ 3155.789778] ---[ end trace 3f9c80825ed62b4f ]---
[ 3156.017948] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[ 3156.018042] usb 3-4: Device not responding to set address.
[ 3156.220683] usb 3-4: Device not responding to set address.
[ 3156.424568] usb 3-4: device not accepting address 16, error -71
[ 3156.720564] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ 3156.747870] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b2fe
[ 3156.747881] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3156.747887] usb 3-4: Product: Integrated Camera
[ 3156.747892] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Vimicro corp.
[ 3156.748576] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b2fe)
[ 3156.749961] input: Integrated Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/input/input24
```

What to do? I hope it is not a hardware problem, since just restarting application without any physical actions help a bit.

Comment: unfortunately this may be a hardware issue. What seems to be happening is when you move your screen the camera gets unplugged then replugged in. It is probably a bad connection and the laptop itself would need to be opened and the connection checked. Usually they are on small ribbon style cables that are clipped into a clip on the motherboard .. this connection can come loose and is probably what is the culprit here

Comment: opening laptops tho... isn't for the weak at heart... they are usually quite a pain in the butt to open .. if you have to .. look for a teardown on the web  or you may go crazy.. there are often hidden screws and garbage and even if you did open it up and find the connection from the camera to the motherboard .. it may be the ribbon cable itself that may have an issue .. .they are made to be extremely flexible but maybe time and heat took its toll and caused it to be damaged in some way so if the connection was good you would have to examine the full run of the flexible cable for damage

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a hardware problem, since it's telling you that the camera was disconnected and then reconnected:

```
usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 15
...
usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
```

The camera is connected using an internal USB cable in the laptop, which is somehow loose , and thus, when you move your laptop, it gets disconnected briefly, and then reconnected, causing the application using it to crash. Webcams in general (and built-in laptop ones especially) are not designed to be disconnected and reconnected while they're in use, and, the applications that use them (cheese) are not written to support this either.

There's no way to fix this with any software changes - you have to open up the laptop and properly connect, or replace the internal ribbon  cable if it's damaged.